# Spring Cloud Gateway: Invalid character '=' for QUERY_PARAM

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-gateway

Spring Boot Starter Parent Version: 2.1.5.RELEASE

When below URL is routed through Spring Cloud Gateway **throwing** Invalid character '=' for Query_Param

**URL:**
http://localhost:8080/tasks/schedules?scheduleName=myschedule-22&taskDefinitionName=mytask&arguments=&properties=scheduler.cron.expression=0%200/1%201/1%20*%20*

**Error:**
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character '=' for QUERY_PARAM in "scheduler.cron.expression=0%200%20*%20*%20MON,THU"

Is there any workaround to overcome it?

The **=** following *scheduler.cron.expression* is causing the issue.
properties=scheduler.cron.expression=0%200/1%201/1%20*%20*

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed in version `spring-cloud-gateway 2.1.1.RELEASE`.

[Refer this for more information](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/pull/467/commits/f198fc26be305b743b1e4b2a956f41036fee265f).

Answer (score 0):

I found posting the query as ***form data*** fixes the issue encountered in the cloud gateway. The = in *properties* value (scheduler.cron.expression=0%200/1%201/1%20*%20*) doesn't cause issue anymore.

Comment: Have an example of this? how do you change the query as form data?